# Private route in react not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm building a project on react. The project has authentication. I use json web token (stateless auth). Also I'm using `react-router-dom` v6 for handling navigation.

The problem that I want to solve is checking auth when navigating through private routes.
Let's say the jwt expires when the user is on a private route, then the user navigates to another private route, I want the user to be redirected to the login page, therefore the way that I'm facing this problem is checking the validity of the jwt everytime a new private route is rendered. Apparently `react-router-dom` is using the same previous private route and the state for `isAuthenticated` variable still true.
I've also thought about use auth context but I'm using refresh token logic implemented via `axios`, so I cannot access the auth context outside a react component to remove the user from context when the refresh token expire.

How can I handle this problem? Is the best solution the one that I'm telling you? Why the private route is not rerendering again when navigating to call `useEffect` again and check the token?
I hope u can help me.

This is the `PrivateRoute` logic

```
export default function PrivateRoute({ children }) {
  const userData = useUserData();
  const api = useContext(ApiContext)
  const auth = useContext(AuthContext)
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(null);

  const checkAuth = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axiosBase.post('/auth/token/verify',{
        token: localStorage.getItem('jwt-access')
      });
      if (res.status == 200) {
        setIsAuthenticated(true)
      } else {
        setIsAuthenticated(false)
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
      setIsAuthenticated(false)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuth()
  }, [])

  if (isAuthenticated == null) {
    return (<div className=''> Loading...</div>)
  }

  return (
    !isAuthenticated ? <Navigate to={'/login'} /> :  (
      children || <Outlet />
    ) 
  )
}
```

And this is how I organize the routes

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/' element={<Layout></Layout>}>
    <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
    /** ADMIN MODULE */
    <Route path='/admin' element={<PrivateRoute></PrivateRoute>}>
      <Route path='newClients' element={
        <NewClients />
      } />
    </Route>
    /** CLIENTS MODULE */
    <Route path='/clients'>
      <Route path='services' element={
        <PrivateRoute>
          <Services />
        </PrivateRoute>
      } />
      <Route path='myServices' element={
        <PrivateRoute>
          <MyServices />
        </PrivateRoute>
      } />
    </Route>
    <Route path='/perfil'>
      <Route index element={<PrivateRoute><Profile /></PrivateRoute>} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
  <Route>
    <Route path='*' element={<HomePage />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path='login' element={<Login />} />
  <Route path='signup' element={<SignUp />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: ```            if (res.status == 200) {
                setIsAuthenticated(true)
            } else {
                setIsAuthenticated(false)
```
Maybe this check should be done in .then callbacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Apparently `react-router-dom` is using the same previous private route
> and the state for `isAuthenticated` variable still true.

This is true when `PrivateRoute` is rendered as a layout route and rendering several nested routes. The same `PrivateRoute` instance only runs the `useEffect` hook once since it has an empty dependency array, so no additional auth checks are done.

Separately when rendering several `PrivateRoute` components as wrapper components or layout route components, they each have their own `isAuthenticated` state. Centralizing the `isAuthenticated` state in a context is a way to force all `PrivateRoute` components to reference the same single source of truth.

The main issue is that the `PrivateRoute` doesn't rerun the auth check when the route changes, it only does so when it mounts.

You should add a "loading" state to the `PrivateRoute` that is active while an auth check is occurring and use the current location as a dependency for the `useEffect` hook to trigger the auth check.

Example:

```
import { Outlet, Navigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function PrivateRoute({ children }) {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  ...

  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState();

  // add loading state, initially true for initial render
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const checkAuth = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true); // <-- set true when starting auth check
    try {
      const res = await axiosBase.post("/auth/token/verify", {
        token: localStorage.getItem("jwt-access")
      });

      setIsAuthenticated(res.status == 200);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      setIsAuthenticated(false);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false); // <-- clear loading state when completed
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuth();
  }, [pathname]); // <-- check auth status on mount/when location changes

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div className="">Loading...</div>;
  }

  return isAuthenticated ? children || <Outlet /> : <Navigate to={"/login"} />;
}
```

[image: Edit private-route-in-react-not-working-as-expected]